# In Laravel, why do I use assertSessionHasErrors() in order to check if there was an error?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel, why do I use assertSessionHasErrors() in order to check if there was an error?
I used this in my feature testing to make sure there is a validation error and it worked, but I don't get why an error is in a session even though I haven't added anything to the session. Do errors go into the session of a response? Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

According Lavavel doc:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

In addition, all of the validation errors and request input will automatically be flashed to the session.